# Postman output ""error": "Not Found", "path": "/api/postService/getPost"

Tags: java, spring-boot, api

I was trying to connect to Postman, but I received an error message that says "error: Not Found, path: /api/postService/getPost". Apache Cassandra is also running perfectly, and I have created a keyspace too.Here is my controller class . can anyone find me the solution?

```
package com.example.foodapiController;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.UUID;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.foodapiEntity.Post;
import com.example.foodapiPostService.*;

@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/postService")
public class PostController {
    
    @Autowired
    PostService postService;

    @PostMapping("/save")
    public ArrayList<Post> submitPost(@RequestBody Post body){
        ArrayList<Post> result=postService.submitPostToDB(body);
        return result;
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/getPost")
    public ArrayList<Post> retrieveAllPost(){
        ArrayList<Post> result=postService.retrivePostFromDB();
        result.sort((e1, e2) -> e2.getDateTime().compareTo(e1.getDateTime()));
        return result;
    }
    
    @DeleteMapping("/delete/{postId}")
    public ArrayList<Post> deleteParticularPost(@PathVariable("postId") UUID postID){
        ArrayList<Post> result=postService.deletePostFromDB(postID);
        return result;
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: What does the requested URL look like in your Postman request?

Comment: looks like this .    http://localhost:8080/api/postService/getPost